# Custom Delegate, dismiss popover from another view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover

I could use some help with custom delegates.  I'm trying to make a protocol that sends a message to its delegate to dismiss the popover view.  Here is what I'm trying.

In the popoverViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol MyPopoverDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) didSelectLanguage;
@end



@interface Popover : UITableViewController{

    id <MyPopoverDelegate> delegate;
    NSMutableArray *languageData;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyPopoverDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

.m

```
@synthesize delegate;

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"You selected %@", [languageData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
    [self.delegate didSelectLanguage];

}

...
```

And in the ViewController that presents the popover

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "popoverViewController.h"




@interface ChoicesChoices : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, MyPopoverDelegate>{

    UIPopoverController *popover;




}
- (IBAction)facebook:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)twitter:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sms:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)copy:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)email:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)home:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)mute:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)note:(id)sender;


@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController* popover;


@end
```

and .m

```
@synthesize popover;

...

- (void)didSelectLanguage{
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"didSelectLanguage fired");
}
```

When I select a row in the table of the popover, didSelectLanguage does not get called.  Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the delegate is not `nil`? In other words, because you don't show the code, I have to ask, did you actually set the delegate to be an instance of your `ChoicesChoices` view controller?

Comment: I'm not sure.  What would that look like?  Would it go in .m?

Comment: See below for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are setting your delegate to the be the view controller that is presenting your popover. Something like this in `ChoicesChoices.m`:

```
- (void)presentPopover
{
  // assuming ARC for all allocations
    Popover *myController = [Popover new];
    myController.delegate = self;
    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myController];
    [self.popover presentPopover...];  // two flavors here, FromRect: and FromBarButtonItem:, that's left up to you to choose which one is correct.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the delegate in the presenting view controller when you create the instance of your custom class.

```
popover.delegate = self
```

Also, it looks like your property is a standard popover controller instead of an instance of your custom view controller.

Comment: Actually, his `popover` property makes sense. It is not meant to be referring to the view controller that the popover contains, but the popover itself. So your `popover.delegate = self;` is in the right direction, wrong object.